# Pass result of Julia `download` to memory instead of file?

Tags: http, julia

With Julia 1.6's `download` function, the typical behavior is to output to a file. How can I save the result directly to something in memory?

E.g. I'd like something like:

```
result = download(url)
contains(result,"hello")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the help text for `download`, use the [Downloads](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Downloads.jl) library; `download` can take an [`IOBuffer`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.IOBuffer). Example:

```
result = String(take!(Downloads.download(url,IOBuffer())))
```

Comment: That library is a Julia 1.6+ feature, so your answer will be correct soon.

Answer (score 0):

Julia uses the curl library, or something similar, for the download function, and that library writes to a file by default, or to stdout, not to a C or Julia string.  Consider that many downloads may be large, perhaps larger than system RAM, to see why.

You could easily extend Julia to download, create a string for the download, and remove the temp file:

```
import Base.download

function Base.download(url::AbstractString, String)
     tmpfile = download(url)
     str = read(tmpfile, String)
     rm(tmpfile)
     return str
 end
```

Watch out for big files though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [UrlDownload.jl](https://github.com/Arkoniak/UrlDownload.jl) library. It uses `HTTP.jl` instead of curl, so it always keep the result in memory, and you can process it on the fly.

```
julia> using UrlDownload

julia> url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arkoniak/UrlDownload.jl/master/data/ext.csv"
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arkoniak/UrlDownload.jl/master/data/ext.csv"

julia> urldownload(url, parser = x -> String(x))
"x,y\n1,2\n3,4\n"
```